# Customer's Session TimeOut in zen-cart

Tags: zen-cart

I have zen-cart's demo site implemented. Customers who are register to my site or have login to my zen-cart site's session time-out is around 1 hour.

Now main question is, I want to decrease my zen-cart customer login session time-out to 10 min. After ideal 10 min customer gets logoff by session time-out.

I have tried one zen-cart's plugin for custom time-out, but it will not get affected. So can any one help me out to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your sessions.php file Zencart grabs the 'session.gc_maxlifetime' from the php.ini file. If you want to change it you should be able to simply define('SESSION_TIMEOUT_CATALOG',16440);or change the session life var. $SESS_LIFE = 12440;

edit : this worked for me, just change this  @ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10440);

includes/functions/sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

On the customer side, Zen Cart doesn't impose a specific session duration. That's handled by your server's PHP configuration.

Change your php.ini setting for session.gc_maxlifetime to whatever you desire it to be.

Comment: I have increase my session time out through configuration file but still front end user who are login to the site will logout after 15 minutes. and I also want to know that how to increase admin session time out? Admin login is also logout after 15 minutes.